Телеграм бот на python telebot
мне нужно написать код, когда бот получает любое сообщение от пользователя он ему отвечал:
сохраняю данные... после чего интервал в 2 секунды
и он сам редактирует сообщение на: загружаю на сервер
и так далее.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил, весь интернет обшерстил и ничего не нашел,
вот мой код:
@bot.message_handler()
    def edit_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'сохраняю данные...')
        time.sleep(2)
        bot.edit_message_text()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка

Не пользуюсь telebot, но могу предложить реализацию такой функции в aiogram.
@user_router.message()
async def edit_text(message: Message):
    import asyncio
    msg = await message.answer("Сохраняю данные...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await bot.edit_message_text("Загружаю на сервер", chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await bot.edit_message_text("Ещё чуть-чуть думаю", chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id)
    # И так далее...


Вероятно в telebot реализация похожая.
